# How to Use UI-tour in Angular 6

Tags: angular6, walkthrough

Anyone have an idea which is the library to use UI-tour or walkthrough in angular application. I don't find any valid library except `ng-walkthrough`. 
My need is the one where we can have more flexibility and supportability with the library.

I have tried with `ngx-bootstrap-product-tour` but it did not work for me. whenever I click on it to start the tour, it's not reflecting anything, I don't see any error or any other problem.

If any suggestions, please let us know.

Comment: Log more and more to see where exactly you stuck. Update the question with your observations which will be easy to help you.

Answer (score 2):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onboarding-overlay

The above link worked for me - the same purpose that you are looking for. The above example uses Angular Material CDK and Overlay to achieve this.

Please find more useful links below that can even support for Angular 6.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-joyride (Pretty Straight Forward)
- https://isaacplmann.github.io/ngx-tour/
- (https://introjs.com/) . https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-7-6-adding-walk-through-introduction-tour-plugin-for-step-by-step-tutorial-in-angular-2-applications/

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap tour library.
here is a bootstrap tour for angular - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-product-tour

demo & docs - https://nmilicic.github.io/ngx-bootstrap-product-tour/